# Google Analytics 4 Event Parameters

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

We have GA4 Enhanced Ecommerce working via GTM on our website. We are tracking all events mentioned in Google's documentation (e.g add_to_cart, begin_checkout, view_item_list).

With events such as '*view_item_list*', '*begin_checkout*' and '*purchase*', we can see them in both 'Realtime' and the GA DebugView (*they even show the 'Items' tab with all items within these events*), and our dataLayer has no issues:

[image]

But when we try to view any of this data in Engagement > Events > 'view_item_list' (for example), the only data displayed is the standard Event Count:

[image: Engagement Events View_item_list]

As you can see from the screenshot, there are no parameters for 'view_item_list'. We are not sure how to get the actual data such as 'item_name' or 'item_list_name' to display.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:

We have now added these item-scoped parameters as custom dimensions:
[image: custom dimensions]

However, it's been over 36 hours since we added these, some of these dimensions/parameters have generated cards but nothing is being generated by the 'Items' parameter.

Any help is still much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Item Names should be available in the "Ecommerce purchases" Report. You do not need to register the parameter as a custom definition for the "item_name" parameter. For example if you upload the "purchase" event in this [example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce#purchase), then the item_name of 'jeggings' will be available in the Ecommerce purchases report:

[image: Ecommerce purchases: Item Name]

What do you see in the Ecommerce purchases report?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Ecommerce is fine. The report is displaying Items. My question is more around the events where the Ecommerce item array is being retrieved via the dataLayer, such as view_item_list and begin_checkout.
In the report, these events show no data about the items or item properties that were retrieved on these events, which is seen in 'Items' tab in debugView. (e.g: which items were viewed in view_item_list event the most). Hence, the custom dimensions for the 'items' based information. Yet, still, no data is available in this dimension. Not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: Hi Brett, I did this example, I saw the event in the Realtime page but I don't have the purchase on the Ecommerce purchases page, do you know what could be wrong please ?

Comment: Hello @DanielG!
I am experiencing the same issue. Do you already found a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Me either, Did you guys solve problem?